# sympref --- 'MatrixWithSquareBrackets' not work

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbols, display

I used sympref('MatrixWithSquareBrackets',true).But raise an error:

```
Expected input to match one of these values:

'FourierParameters', 'HeavisideAtOrigin', 'AbbreviateOutput', 'TypesetOutput'

The input, 'MatrixWithSquareBrackets', did not match any of the valid values.

Error in Untitled3 (line 7)
sympref('MatrixWithSquareBrackets',true);
```

I want to use symbolic matrix square brackets in my answer.How can I do this?

Comment: That functionality is introduced in R2019a. You are using an older MATLAB version

Comment: Thank you @Sardar Usama.Is there a way to do this in previous versions?

Comment: Yes, why not! This is what programmers do. But this seems too broad to ask here